# How can I get pg_dump to authenticate properly

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have tried using host variable `PGPASSWORD` and `.pgpass` and neither of these two will allow me to authenticate to the database. I have `chmod`'d `.pgpass` to appropriate permissions and also tried:

```
export PGPASSWORD=mypass and PGPASSWORD=mypass
```

The password DOES contain a `\` however I was encasing it in single quotes `PGPASS='mypass\'` and it still will not authenticate.

I'm running:

```
pg_dump dbname -U username -Fc
```

and I still receive

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dbname" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "username"
```

Comment: That "...Peer authentication..." part of the error message means that it's not using [password authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) at all.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

**The Quick Solution**

The problem is that it's trying to perform local [`peer`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) authentication based on your current username. If you would like to use a password you must specify the hostname with `-h`.

```
pg_dump dbname -U username -h localhost -F c
```

**Explanation**

This is due to the following in your [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

```
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

This tells Postgres to use `peer` authentication for local users which requires the postgres username to match your current system username. The second line refers to connections using a hostname and will allow you to authenticate with a password via the [`md5`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD) method.

**My Preferred Development Config**

**NOTE**: This should only be used on single-user workstations. This could lead to a major security vulnerability on a production or multi-user machine.

When developing against a local postgres instance I like to change my local authentication method to [`trust`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST). This will allow connecting to postgres via a local unix socket as any user with no password. It can be done by simply changing `peer` above to `trust` and reloading postgres.

```
# Don't require a password for local connections
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Comment: For anyone unsure where your conf file is: use `sudo locate pg_hba.conf` -- it has to be sudo since the postgres user will be the only one with access to the directory (I think).

Comment: your command worked for me but i can not find out where it is, or what is the name of file, how can i find that file?

Comment: If I configure my Postgres inside Docker, will this setup work for connections coming my localhost?

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes you can use

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump ...
```

Comment: For the purposes a scheduling a cron to perform routine backups as root this won't work.

Comment: ... but still works for the purposes a scheduling a cron to perform routine backups as postgres.

Comment: @RabbanKeyak Sure, but what good is that if you need to copy it to the cloud or backup directly to a mounted network folder that `postgres` isn't the owner of? Correct me if I'm wrong, but unless you modify the `postgres` user there is no password to perform `sudo` actions. But then if you need to do anything cron-related that involves `sudo` then you should just create a root cron.

Comment: @TheMet4lGod In case you are copying it to the cloud, it will be request for authorization from the cloud not depending on which user you are at the moment: root, postgres, whatever. In general cases.
In case you need to make dump directly to a directory without permissions it's usually possible to add permissions; to make it through intermediate directory (and setup another root cron to copy the dump from it to destination directory); to use root cron with something like `su - -c 'pg_dump ...' postgres > /path/for/dump`.

Comment: @RabbanKeyak That has not been my experiences. You just configure `rclone` and then you can just copy to the cloud pretty effortlessly. I could probably reduce the number of steps, but I use `pg_dump` to backup the database to a local directory on the server then use `rclone` to send it to the cloud (i.e., Backblaze B2, AWS, etc.). This can be set up as a daily cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look this up again after figuring it out a few weeks ago for work (but trying to set up a postgresql database at home now), but you may want to modify your `pg_hba.conf` file.

What I did is comment out the default "local" specification as it authenticates all local users using the `peer` method. This post from [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72976) helped shed some light on this.

In the end, your `pg_hba.conf` file should look something like this:

```bash
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     peer
local   <db_name>    <user>                                   password
```

Then, if you want to schedule the backup with cron or something all you have to do after restarting the service is:

```bash
PGPASSWORD=$(cat /home/<user>/.pg-pass) pg_dump -Fc -U <pg_user> -d <db_name> > /home/<user>/<db_name>.dump
```

Where the dump file is output is irrelevant so I just put it in my home folder for the time being, but for work I have this same style code setup in a script that creates a daily backup and then `rclone` to the cloud.